# Why does struts-config_1_3.dtd not permit page as a valid scope?

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am developing an application in netbeans 8.1 using the Struts 1.3 framework and a jsp needs to have a scope as page however that is not an offered action scope although I can enter it and the application works.  However when I try to add another Action class the wizard (rightly) complains with 'The configuration file contains errors.'

Is this an oversight or is there a good reason why I shouldn't use page scope?

Comment: There's rarely a reason to; why not use request scope?

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that Struts-1 was EOLed nearly 4 years ago, and hasn't had an official update in 8 years.  You really shouldn't be doing *new* development using this framework anymore.  (If you're doing maintenance, that's something different, and I hope you'll be given the time to migrate to a different framework soon)